# unity game engine can run in Raspberry Pi 4 4GB with raspbian OS

Tags: unity-game-engine, raspberry-pi, game-development, raspberry-pi4

I am planning to buy a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB for game development and coding. I am planning to use the Unity game engine for game development.

Can the Unity game engine run on a Raspberry Pi 4 4GB with Raspbian OS?

Comment: Have you done *any* research on this topic yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would work.
The Raspberry Pi uses an ARM-based processor. Unity's editor requires an x86-64-based processor.
I wouldn't even recommend it.
4GB of RAM is quite low and in terms of graphics cards, it is basically nothing.

In short, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry PI gpu performance is too low